# Add button as last UICollectionViewCell if all cells do not fit

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

My UICollection view should have no more than two rows. If all cells do not fit, it should add "Show More" button as last cell. Cells have dynamic width and UICollectionView is non scrollable.

What are my options?

**EDIT**

I guess I should check if all cell fits into the screen, maybe using `collectionView.visibleCells`. If they do not fit, I should probably insert my "Show More" cell. Does this sound reasonable? Any other ideas?

Oh, and all cells have dynamic width.

Comment: How about adding a third cell that has text "Show More"?

Comment: @almas I've clarified my question a little bit, because based on your suggestion, you either were trolling or my question was extremely unclear